# Cannot assign value through Promises in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was trying to expose a variable into a Component HTML. The variable should go through `cl.getMonitors` to fetch the value from response. However, the variable `Site.name` was shown as initially assigned `Agenda` yet `console.dir(res)` was shown in the console. Can anyone please help?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Client from 'uptime-robot';

const apiKey = 'asdasdasdasdasdasd';

const cl = new Client(apiKey);

var Site = { 
  name: 'Agenda',
  status: ''
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})

export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  siteStatus: string; 
  siteName: string;

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    cl.getMonitors({customUptimeRatio: [1, 7, 30]}, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.dir(res);

      this.siteName = res[0].friendlyname;
      this.siteStatus = res[0].status;
    });
    this.siteName = Site.name;
    this.siteStatus = Site.status;

  }

}
```

Comment: what does your template and cl.getMonitors look like?

Comment: <p class='page-title'>{{siteName}} Dashboard</p>
<p class='msg success'>Status - {{siteStatus}}</p>

Comment: Try putting `this.siteName = Site.name;` and `this.siteStatus = Site.status;` above `cl.getMonitors(...)` line.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Getting no errors at all, saw the response is logged in the console, but HTML template seems to be rendered before calling the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple suspicious code there. Which might be causing this issue -

> 1. Is sequence of req and res right ?

Lootk the following line. First argument is `err` and second is `res`. Generally it is reversed so check if the sequence is right.

```
  cl.getMonitors({customUptimeRatio: [1, 7, 30]}, function (err, res) {
```

> 2. Check the response format

You accessing the first index element from the response ? Is the right one or it should be like - Share your `json` for confirmation

```
  this.siteName = res.friendlyname;
  this.siteStatus = res.status;
```

> 3 `this` in `getMonitors` might have wrong context.

You are using the `this` to get the `siteStatus` and `siteName` however context might have been changed and it is pointing to wrong context.

**You can use following syntax to get this**

```
   cl.getMonitors({customUptimeRatio: [1, 7, 30]}, (err, res) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("this ", this);
      this.siteName = res[0].friendlyname;
      this.siteStatus = res[0].status;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, you were right about 3, the `this` object is not referring to the component, but rather than `window` itself.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you.